# Entity Framework Core Model Builder with inherited class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How can I use an inherited class with Entity Framework Core 3.1's model builder?

Here is my base class:

```
public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        Addresses = new List<Address>();
        Contacts = new List<Contact>();
    }

    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    public string WebsiteURL { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

This is my class which inherits from is:

```
public class Organisation : Company 
{
    public Organisation() : base()
    {

    }

    public string OrganisationMasterCode { get; set; } = $"Something unique"; 
}
```

and here is my modelbuilder which does not work as Addresses and Contacts are not accessible:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Company is fine:
    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(i => i.Addresses).WithOne(i => i.Company);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(i => i.Contacts).WithOne(i => i.Company);

    // Below i.Organisation does not work
    modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>().HasMany(i => i.Addresses).WithOne(i => i.Organisation);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>().HasMany(i => i.Contacts).WithOne(i => i.Organisation);
}
```

ModelContext.cs(61, 90): [CS1061] 'Address' does not contain a definition for 'Organisation' and no accessible extension method 'Organisation' accepting a first argument of type 'Address' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

ModelContext.cs(62, 89): [CS1061] 'Contact' does not contain a definition for 'Organisation' and no accessible extension method 'Organisation' accepting a first argument of type 'Contact' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can you please add compilation/runtime error and code for `Address` and `Contact` entities?

Comment: Added compilation errors

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - there is no field/property `Organisation` on `Address` and `Contact` types.

Comment: Yes but an address/contact should not have both a company and an organisaton, it should have either one or the other, so I was hoping to use the base company type in both scenarios.